# How to handle spaces in awk file comparison

Tags: awk

I have two sets of input to the awk script. File 1 and File2 are identical. Similarly file3 and File4 are identical.
But when I do the comparison using awk then code doesn't work properly for file3 and file4.

**code:**

```
BEGIN { FS="[= ]" }
{
    match(" "$0,/ issuer_grid_id="[^"]+"/)
    key = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    match(" "$0,/ match_key="[^"]+"/)
    key = key substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
NR==FNR {
    file1[key] = $0
    next
}
{
    if ( key in file1 ) {
        nf = split(file1[key],tmp)
        for (i=1; i<nf; i+=2) {
            f1[key,tmp[i]] = tmp[i+1]
        }

        msg = sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
            if ( $(i+1) != f1[key,$i] ) {
                msg = msg sep OFS ARGV[1] "." $i "=" f1[key,$i] OFS FILENAME "." $i "=" $(i+1)
                sep = ","
            }
        }
        if ( msg != "" ) {
            print "Mismatch for key " key msg
        }
        delete file1[key]
    }
    else {
        file2[key] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (key in file1) {
        print "In file1 only:", key, file1[key]
    }
    for (key in file2) {
        print "In file2 only:", key, file2[key]
    }
}
```

**File1**

```
period="2021-02-28" book_base_ent_cd="U0028" intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated" src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1" dflt_stts_issr="Not in default" src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1" dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default" src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC" prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book" imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)" src_imprmnt_stts="1" imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed" unit_measure="USD" issuer_grid_id="2" match_key="PLCHS252SA20"
```

**File2**

```
period="2021-02-28" book_base_ent_cd="U0028" intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated" src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1" dflt_stts_issr="Not in default" src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1" dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default" src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC" prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book" imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)" src_imprmnt_stts="1" imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed" unit_measure="USD" issuer_grid_id="2" match_key="PLCHS252SA20"
```

**File3:**

```
period="2021-02-28" book_base_ent_cd="U0027" other_inst_ident="PLCHS258Q463" rep_nom_curr="PLN" reporting_basis="Unit" src_instr_class="Debt" mat_date="2026-08-25" nom_curr="PLN" primary_asset_class="Bond" seniority_type="931" security_status="alive" issuer_name="CUST38677608" intra_group_prud_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated" src_frbrnc_stts="NOFRBRNRNGT" prfrmng_stts="Performing" src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1" dflt_stts_issr="Not in default" src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1" dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default" src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC" prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book" imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)" src_imprmnt_stts="1" imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed" src_imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="COLLECTIVE" accmltd_imprmnt="78.54" accmltd_chngs_fv_cr="0" expsr_vl="0" unit_measure="EUR" unit_measure_nv="EUR" crryng_amnt="24565.13" issuer_grid_id="38677608" match_key="PLCHS258Q463"
```

**File4:**

```
period="2021-02-28" book_base_ent_cd="U0027" other_inst_ident="PLCHS258Q463" rep_nom_curr="PLN" reporting_basis="Unit" src_instr_class="Debt" mat_date="2026-08-25" nom_curr="PLN" primary_asset_class="Bond" seniority_type="931" security_status="alive" issuer_name="CUST38677608" intra_group_prud_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group" frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated" src_frbrnc_stts="NOFRBRNRNGT" prfrmng_stts="Performing" src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1" dflt_stts_issr="Not in default" src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1" dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default" src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC" prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book" imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)" src_imprmnt_stts="1" imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed" src_imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="COLLECTIVE" accmltd_imprmnt="78.54" accmltd_chngs_fv_cr="0" expsr_vl="0" unit_measure="EUR" unit_measure_nv="EUR" crryng_amnt="24565.13" issuer_grid_id="38677608" match_key="PLCHS258Q463"
```

**Output for File1 and File2**

```
 awk -f compare.awk file1 file2
$
```

**Output for File3 and File4**

```
awk -f compare.awk file3 file4
Mismatch for key issuer_grid_id="38677608" match_key="PLCHS258Q463"  file1."KC10.1"=dflt_stts_instrmnt file2."KC10.1"=dflt_stts_issr, file1.default"=src_mes_accntng_clssfctn file2.default"=src_dflt_stts_issr, file1."0"=unit_measure file2."0"=expsr_vl, file1."EUR"=crryng_amnt file2."EUR"=unit_measure_nv
```

How the input in second set (file3 and file4) differs and how spaces can be handled in the quoted strings of input?

Thanks and Regards !!!

Comment: Do you have or can you get GNU awk? Can your quoted strings contain `=` or [escaped] `"` (e.g. `foo="stuff=""bar"""` or `foo="stuff=\"bar\""`)?

Comment: Please condense your example to have 2 input files and 1 output file instead of 4 input files, etc. so it's easier for us to copy/paste to test with.

Comment: I would also suggest cutting down the size of the input files to just enough `name=value` pairs to demonstrate the logic (eg, the 2 key pairs, another pair without spaces, another pair with spaces)

Comment: and reducing the length of each string. We shouldn't need scroll bars to see your data, those lengthy strings add no value and make it harder to see the contents.

Comment: @EdMorton : I have GNU awk on my unix box. awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.7
No, My quoted strings won't contain = or [escaped] "

Comment: That's an extremely old version, abut 15 years out of date, we're now on 5.1.1. Can you upgrade as you're missing a ton of useful functionality (including `FPAT`) and some bug fixes?

Comment: I completely understand that the long inputs are not preferable and difficult to read. But I observed for small input code seems to work. For example, File1(or File2) is subset of File3(or File4) and all the files contain spaces in quoted strings. But I am having issue only for File3(or File4). Apologies, But that's what I observed.

Comment: The issues you're having aren't related to the length of your strings, they''re related to the **content** of your strings. Instead of `issuer_name="CUST38677608" intra_group_prud_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group"` you could have created your sample input to use `name="CUST3" scope="foo bar"` and it'd have been testing exactly the same functionality and you don't need multiple strings with the same contents.

Comment: The key when posting a question is to come up with (or observe in your case) input data that causes problems and then create and post a [mcve] that can reproduce those problems, not just post whatever lengthy data you saw those problems in. Doing that makes it much easier for us to be able to help you.

Comment: You say in your comments [My quoted strings won't contain =](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973942/how-to-handle-spaces-in-awk-file-comparison#comment125469817_70973942) but your sample input contains many things like `unit_measure_nv="= file2.EUR"` (note the `=` within  the quoted string).

Answer (score 1):

To help you with this and any future tasks you want to perform on your data - using any awk, here's how to identify your tag-value pairs in all of your input files and create key values for them:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    numTags = mkTag2val($0,tag2val)
    key = tag2val["issuer_grid_id"] RS tag2val["match_key"]
    print "----" ORS FILENAME, "<" key ">", numTags
    for (tag in tag2val) {
        printf "\t%s=\"%s\"\n", tag, tag2val[tag]
    }
}

function mkTag2val(str,tag2val,         tag,val,cnt) {
    delete tag2val
    while ( match(str,/[^ ]+="[^"]*"/) ) {
        ++cnt
        tag = val = substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        sub(/=.*/,"",tag)
        gsub(/^[^=]+="|"$/,"",val)
        tag2val[tag] = val
        str = substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
    return cnt+0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file{1..4}
----
file1 <2
PLCHS252SA20> 16
        dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default"
        period="2021-02-28"
        imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)"
        imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed"
        issuer_grid_id="2"
        intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group"
        prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book"
        dflt_stts_issr="Not in default"
        src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1"
        src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC"
        src_imprmnt_stts="1"
        src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1"
        book_base_ent_cd="U0028"
        unit_measure="USD"
        frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated"
        match_key="PLCHS252SA20"
----
file2 <2
PLCHS252SA20> 16
        dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default"
        period="2021-02-28"
        imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)"
        imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed"
        issuer_grid_id="2"
        intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group"
        prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book"
        dflt_stts_issr="Not in default"
        src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1"
        src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC"
        src_imprmnt_stts="1"
        src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1"
        book_base_ent_cd="U0028"
        unit_measure="USD"
        frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated"
        match_key="PLCHS252SA20"
----
file3 <38677608
PLCHS258Q463> 35
        expsr_vl="0"
        dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default"
        src_frbrnc_stts="NOFRBRNRNGT"
        src_instr_class="Debt"
        other_inst_ident="PLCHS258Q463"
        accmltd_chngs_fv_cr="0"
        nom_curr="PLN"
        period="2021-02-28"
        prfrmng_stts="Performing"
        imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)"
        seniority_type="931"
        accmltd_imprmnt="78.54"
        imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed"
        issuer_grid_id="38677608"
        intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group"
        src_imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="COLLECTIVE"
        prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book"
        dflt_stts_issr="Not in default"
        src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1"
        rep_nom_curr="PLN"
        src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC"
        security_status="alive"
        mat_date="2026-08-25"
        crryng_amnt="24565.13"
        unit_measure_nv="EUR"
        src_imprmnt_stts="1"
        src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1"
        issuer_name="CUST38677608"
        primary_asset_class="Bond"
        book_base_ent_cd="U0027"
        unit_measure="EUR"
        frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated"
        intra_group_prud_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group"
        reporting_basis="Unit"
        match_key="PLCHS258Q463"
----
file4 <38677608
PLCHS258Q463> 35
        expsr_vl="0"
        dflt_stts_instrmnt="Not in default"
        src_frbrnc_stts="NOFRBRNRNGT"
        src_instr_class="Debt"
        other_inst_ident="PLCHS258Q463"
        accmltd_chngs_fv_cr="0"
        nom_curr="PLN"
        period="2021-02-28"
        prfrmng_stts="Performing"
        imprmnt_stts="Stage 1 (IFRS)"
        seniority_type="931"
        accmltd_imprmnt="78.54"
        imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="Collectively assessed"
        issuer_grid_id="38677608"
        intra_group_acc_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group"
        src_imprmnt_assssmnt_mthd="COLLECTIVE"
        prdntl_prtfl="Non-trading book"
        dflt_stts_issr="Not in default"
        src_prfrmng_stts="KC10.1"
        rep_nom_curr="PLN"
        src_mes_accntng_clssfctn="AMC"
        security_status="alive"
        mat_date="2026-08-25"
        crryng_amnt="24565.13"
        unit_measure_nv="EUR"
        src_imprmnt_stts="1"
        src_dflt_stts_issr="KC10.1"
        issuer_name="CUST38677608"
        primary_asset_class="Bond"
        book_base_ent_cd="U0027"
        unit_measure="EUR"
        frbrnc_stts="Not forborne or renegotiated"
        intra_group_prud_scope="Issuer is not part of the reporting group"
        reporting_basis="Unit"
        match_key="PLCHS258Q463"
```

Apply that technique to your existing code and then ask a new question showing your modified code if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the current code's logic is valid and the real issue here is how to parse data based on two different field defintiions so fwiw ...

Assumptions:

- need to split the input record based on either `string before an equal sign` or `everything inside a pair of double quotes`
- double quotes only used as delimiters (ie, double quotes do not show up as escaped characters)
- equal sign does not show up inside pairs of double quotes

A couple small changes to OP's current code:

- instead of `FS` (field separator) we'll define the structure of the actual fields using a custom `FPAT` (field pattern)
- this change (`FS` => `FPAT`) requires we replace `split()` (based on `FS`) calls with `patsplit()` (based on `FPAT`) calls (see [GNU awk string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html))

Our `FPAT` definition:

- `FPAT="(\\<[^=]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"`
- 1st field pattern definition: `(\\<[^=]+)`:
- `\<` designates a left-side word boundary
- `[^=]+` is everything that's not an equal sign
- 2nd field pattern definition: `(\"[^\"]+\")"`:
- start with a double quote (`\"`) followed by one or more non-equal-sign characters (`[^\"]+`) followed by a double quote (`\"`)

**NOTE:** requires `GNU awk` (at least `version 4.0`) for [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) and the [\< word boundary](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html)

Making these 2 changes to OP's current code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FPAT="(\\<[^=]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" }            ### replace FS with FPAT
{
    match(" "$0,/ issuer_grid_id="[^"]+"/)
    key = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    match(" "$0,/ match_key="[^"]+"/)
    key = key substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
}
NR==FNR {
    file1[key] = $0
    next
}
{
    if ( key in file1 ) {
        nf = patsplit(file1[key],tmp)               ### replace split() with patsplit()
        for (i=1; i<nf; i+=2) {
            f1[key,tmp[i]] = tmp[i+1]
        }

        msg = sep = ""
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) {
            if ( $(i+1) != f1[key,$i] ) {
                msg = msg sep OFS ARGV[1] "." $i "=" f1[key,$i] OFS FILENAME "." $i "=" $(i+1)
                sep = ","
            }
        }
        if ( msg != "" ) {
            print "Mismatch for key " key msg
        }
        delete file1[key]
    }
    else {
        file2[key] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (key in file1) {
        print "In file1 only:", key, file1[key]
    }
    for (key in file2) {
        print "In file2 only:", key, file2[key]
    }
}
'
```

Running this against OP's current `file3` and `file4` generates nothing as output:

```
$ awk -f compare.awk file1 file2
$
$ awk -f compare.awk file3 file4
$
```

Adding 3 new files to the mix:

- `file5` - same as `file4` except for `period="2021-02-29"`
- `file6` - same as `file4` except for `book_base_ent_cd="U0030"`
- `file7` - same as `file4` except for `issuer_grid_id="X8677608"` (ie, we're modifying the key)

Running the new code against these additional files:

```
$ awk -f compare.awk file4 file5
Mismatch for key issuer_grid_id="38677608" match_key="PLCHS258Q463" file4.period="2021-02-28" file5.period="2021-02-29"

$ awk -f compare.awk file4 file6
Mismatch for key issuer_grid_id="38677608" match_key="PLCHS258Q463" file4.book_base_ent_cd="U0027" file6.book_base_ent_cd="U0030"

$ awk -f compare.awk file4 file7
In file1 only: ...
In file2 only: ...
```

Comment: Thanks. After making these changes I get error - awk: compare.awk:15: (FILENAME=file2 FNR=1) fatal: function `patsplit' not defined.  my awk version is GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: from this [GNU feature history](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Feature-History.html) it appears `patsplit()` was introduced with `version 4.0`; I don't know what the date would've been for `version 4.0` but I'm guessing it's been quite a few years; we're currently up to `version 5.1` ... can you update your verison of [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)?

Comment: Okay let me try that. It might take several days. I''ll try to upgrade the version and then will try your solution. Thanks again!!